# Windows Installer in XML

Tags: wix, wix3.5

When uninstalling my app, I'd like to configure the WiX setup to remove directories and like user settings and user data I want add a dialog with two check boxes and optionally remove all the files that were added. It looks like the uninstaller removes only the directories and files that were originally installed from the MSI file .

In other words, **I want to give user a chance to Delete his data with a dialog while uninstall is called ?**

Is this possible through WiX without resorting to custom actions? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be storing user settings and data in the "AppData" folder, not in the installation location.  This avoids the need for this dialog altogether, does it not?

Comment: But I am not storing user settings and data in the "installation location" folder, I am storing them in "AppData". So, by default the user's data doesn't get deleted. The problem is I want to provide an option for the user to delete this data via something like a dialog with checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry, re-read your question and it seems I misunderstood it.  The second paragraph is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this without using custom actions, see the WiX documentation regarding the RemoveFile and RemoveFolder elements. You can use these to remove files and folders on uninstallation. RemoveFolder will only work if the folder is empty.

Note that if the files are located in the user's application data directory, you will only be able to do this for the user that is uninstalling the application. You cannot easily do it for all users.

Comment: +1 for "You cannot easily do it for all users". Once it's in a user folder, it's *user data* not application data, so you want to be double-sure before trying to do it.